# How to use the with_items in wait_for module if I've created more than one instance?

Tags: ansible, ansible-role

The yml I've written works properly if I've created only one ec2instance but in case I've to provision more than 1 ec2 instances then this yml code fails.

I want to wait for the ssh to come up for 2 different ec2 instances

```
 - name: 7. Wait for SSH to come up
   local_action: wait_for
                 host={{ item.public_ip }}
                 port=22
                 state=started
   with_items: "{{ ec2.instances }}"
```